# Liquid FX order by CCXT

Tags: parameters, liquid, ccxt

I want to place order by CCXT in the Liquid exchange. I think we need to specify 'params' to get things done. For example,

import ccxt

from pprint import pprint

bf = ccxt.bitflyer()

ticker = bf.fetch_ticker('BTC/JPY', params = { "product_code" : "FX_BTC_JPY" })

pprint(ticker)

In this case, I know "product_code" is "FX_BTC_JPY" for bitFlyer, but I don't know what it should be for Liquid.

If you know what is the "product_code" or any item to be specified in "params" for Liquid FX, please tell me.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please edit your question so the code is in a code block in body of question instead of regular text. [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: As far as I can see CCXT doesn't support Liquid FX exchange as it's not in the list of supported exchanges. Are you sure you can use CCXT with Liquid FX? https://github.com/ccxt/ccxt/blob/master/doc/exchange-markets.rst There's an exchange called Liquid but that's different from Liquid FX.